# How to send back data to Chrome Extension from webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-chrome, response, webapp2

I have a Chrome Extension which sends data to Google App Engine(webapp2).

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {

if (message.paragraphs_ready) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://my_website.appspot.com/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'paragraphs_ready': message.paragraphs_ready},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
            alert("Server received my data");
        }
    });
}

});
```

GAE(webapp2) processes data and should send a response back to Chrome Extension. I don't want to go for Channel Python API if possible.

```
class DataProcessing(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """This Handler is responsible for the Processing"""
    def post(self):

    to_be_processed = cgi.escape(self.request.POST['paragraphs_ready'])

    def my_proc(to_be_processed):
        return to_be_processed

    self.response.write(my_proc(to_be_processed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`success` function on ajax request is called when the server responds not when the client sends a request.

So in your case you would have something like this:

```
success: function(data){
    alert("Server received my data AND sent a response");
    alert(data);
}
```

> **success**: A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function
>   gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server,
>   formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the
>   status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of
>   jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each
>   function will be called in turn.

See more here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The problem is that GAE doesn't send back data.

Comment: Does `my_proc(to_be_processed)` return any data?

Comment: Yes, I just don't know how to use `self.response.write(my_proc(to_be_processed))` so data is sent back.

Comment: There's nothing else to know. `self.response.write(my_proc(to_be_processed))` will send data back to the client as long as `my_proc(to_be_processed)` returns data. The formatting is off in your Python' handler code. Can you fix it first to make sure that's not the issue?